# JQuery closest not finding class

Tags: jquery

I have the following structure which has several rows like:

```
<tr class="tableRow">
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td><button id="13" class="deleteMailshot" type="button"></button></td>
</tr>
```

I want to perform an ajax call to delete the mailshot chosen then remove the row.

I'm using `.closest()` but it's not finding it... here's what I'm trying:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/ajax/actions/deleteMailshot.php',
    data: {mailshot_id:mailshot_id},
    success:  function(data) {
        $(this).closest('.tableRow').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

I've also tried:

```
$(this).parent().parent('.tableRow').fadeOut();
```

Comment: I doubt that `$(this)` in `success` refers to some unexpected thing, try seeing/viewing the console for any possible error.

Comment: @KingKing - per [the jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), `this` in the success handler points to the ajax settings object used in the ajax call.  But, as I described in my answer, one can use the `context` property to tell jQuery what you want `this` to be set to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
var self = $(this);
$.ajax({
  ....
  success:  function(data) {
    self.closest('.tableRow').fadeOut(); // use self
```

Answer (score 4):

Assign this to a variable before the `AJAX`. This refers to something else inside the anonymous function on `success`.

E.g.

```
var $button = $(this);
```

Then use:

```
$button.closest...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `context` option for the ajax call to control what the `this` pointer will be set to inside your success handler:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/ajax/actions/deleteMailshot.php',
    data: {mailshot_id:mailshot_id},
    context: this,
    success:  function(data) {
        $(this).closest('.tableRow').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

By default, `this` in the success handler points to the ajax settings object used in the call, but if there is no need for a reference to that object, then setting the `context` property allows you to keep `this` the same as it was when you called `$.ajax()` so you can use it directly without the work-around offered in the other answers.